# Is the inverse of Minkowski's question mark function continuous on the dyadic fractions?

Tags: general-topology, continued-fractions

I'm looking for a continuous function from the dyadic fractions between 0 and 1 to the rational numbers between 0 and 1. The inverse of Minkowski's question mark (also known as Conway's box function) seems like a candidate, but I'm not certain that it is in fact continuous.

Comment: Inverse of strictly monotonic continuous function is continuous.

Comment: Do you where I can find out more about this box function ; and does $$?^{-1}x=1-?^{-1}x$$ where $?$ is minkowskis function $x \in \text{Im}(?)$ is an element of the image of minkowski's question mark function. Holds for minkowski's function wherever the inverse is defined ?(if its not bijective, but I presume its inverse function exists somewhere because the function is a monotonically strictly increasing function)? In any case do you whether this inverse identity and standard identity (the 2nd in). <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question_mark_function>, have an official name